# Not able to link libsvn_delta-1.a when compiling svn_swig_perl in msys

Tags: ld

Trying to compile perl svn binding for msys. But when compiling the swig perl **lib_core.dll** it complains reference not found for **_svn_delta_noop_window_handler** and **_svn_delta_default_editor** in **libsvn_swig_perl-1.a**. Both function coming from **libsvn_delta-1.a**.

I should recompile and make sure the **libsvn_swig_perl-1.a** properly link with **libsvn_delta-1.a**? Or it doesn't matter as long as during building **lib_core.dll** it can link the missing static library?

I really have no idea how to solve this issue.

below are the full log when compile the **lib_core.dll**:

```
ld2  -s core.o  -o blib/arch/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.dll   \
  /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE/libperl.dll.a -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_client/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_delta/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_repos/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_wc/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_diff/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_subr/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_local/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_neon/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_util/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/.libs -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_delta-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_ra-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_wc-1 -lsvn_diff-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lsvn_fs_util-1 -lsvn_swig_perl-1 -lapr-1 -lintl -lz -laprutil-1 -lexpat -lperl -L/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE        \ 
gcc -shared -o _Core.dll -Wl,--out-implib=lib_Core.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--stack,8388608 -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base \
-s core.o  /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE/libperl.dll.a -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_client/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_delta/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_repos/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_wc/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_diff/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_subr/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_local/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_neon/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_util/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/.libs -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_delta-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_ra-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_wc-1 -lsvn_diff-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lsvn_fs_util-1 -lsvn_swig_perl-1 -lapr-1 -lintl -lz -laprutil-1 -lexpat -lperl -L/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE
Creating library file: lib_Core.dll.a
/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/.libs/libsvn_swig_perl-1.a(swigutil_pl.o.b): In function `thunk_apply_textdelta':
/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/subversion-1.6.17/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.c:703: undefined reference to `_svn_delta_noop_window_handler'
/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/.libs/libsvn_swig_perl-1.a(swigutil_pl.o.b): In function `svn_delta_make_editor':
/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/subversion-1.6.17/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.c:785: undefined reference to `_svn_delta_default_editor'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
perlld: *** system() failed to execute
gcc -shared -o _Core.dll -Wl,--out-implib=lib_Core.dll.a -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--stack,8388608 -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base \
-s core.o  /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE/libperl.dll.a -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_client/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_delta/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_repos/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_wc/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_diff/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_subr/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_local/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_ra_neon/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_util/.libs -L/usr/src/subversion16/subversion-1.6.17-3-msys-src/bld/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/.libs -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_delta-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_ra-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_wc-1 -lsvn_diff-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lsvn_fs_util-1 -lsvn_swig_perl-1 -lapr-1 -lintl -lz -laprutil-1 -lexpat -lperl -L/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys/CORE
```

Answer (score 0):

My question already answer by other post. Its the linker order issue. Check the answer below:
[Linker order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717376/860364)

I just need to move around the linker for svn_swig_perl to link it before svn_delta to solve the problem.